# Is it possible to get the statistical significance of the mean of a distribution inferred through a Bayesian Approach?

Tags: regression, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, hierarchical-bayesian

I am new to Bayesian inference and I am not sure if this problem and question are well-posed.

When estimating the coefficients of a linear regression we can evaluate the statistical significance of the parameters against the null hp that the coefficient parameter is equal to zero..

When doing the same through Bayesian inference it is possible and it makes sense to determine the statistical significance of the mean of the distribution against the null hp that the mean is equal to 0?

In a **Google paper** [(this one)](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45999.pdf) they used a Bayesian approach for the regression parameters estimation.
This is an excerpt from the Bayesian equation I am  talking about:
[image]

and this an excerpt from "**Introduction to probability and statistics for engineers and scientists**" written by Sheldon Ross. Is the chapter about the linear regression and the inference about the parameters where I studied 10 years ago

[image]
[image]

Comment: in practice, folks will calculate analogs to one-sided p-values by looking at the posterior probability that a given coefficient is greater than (or below) zero.

Comment: Bayesians usually don't think in terms of hypothesis tests. Instead, the posterior for your regression coefficient will tell you [which values are plausible and with which probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/362717).